# Minecraft launcher saying it's already running when it isn't

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

[image: gamealreadyrunning]

I have no idea how to fix this. Clicking "Start anyway" crashes the launcher by the way. I have already tried reinstalling Minecraft (3 times), I've restarted my computer countless times and there is no instances of Java running in my task manager when this error occurs. I have found no answer that fixes this online.

P.S. If somehow I have been hacked and that's why my account is running somewhere else, why have they had my account running for a month? Yes, that's how long I have been trying to fix this.

Comment: did you check the task manager?

Comment: I said no java or minecraft in the task manager

Comment: welcome to Arqade! firstly, it definitely isn't an account hack, as it wouldn't be giving the error of "running in this game directory". secondly, you said you attempted to kill every instance of Java and Minecraft you found and have tried thrice to reinstall Minecraft, right? have you tried to back up your saves and resource packs and *completely delete the ``%appdata%/.minecraft``* folder?

Answer (score 1):

If this were happening to me and I had already done the following things.

1. Kill all java process. Test Minecraft.
2. Reboot computer. Test Minecraft.
3. Reinstall the game. Test Minecraft.

After all that if I still had the problem I would backup and then delete ALL the Minecraft directories and reinstall a final time followed by testing Minecraft again. Now, if I still had this problem I would start to get suspicious about malware/virus/whatnot and I would use a tool to find which processes have open file handles on my Minecraft files with this tool

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

If I found processes that had open file handles on my Minecraft files I would then investigate each process and research them on the internet. At this point I would expect to find malware or the alike. Then I would begin the long process of sorting out that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same problem, but for me, all I have to do is wait after seeing the message. If I click start anyway and play, it lags really bad and eventually crashes, but if I don’t press anything, Minecraft eventually comes up in a new tab, and I can play just fine.

Give this a shot and determine whether or not it works for you. The source of this issue may vary from user to user.